# Break the row after each 10th td inside a for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to break after each 10th element in the array. How do I create it inside of the current for loop?

```
function printa() {
    document.write('<table>');
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        document.write("<td>" + numbers[i] + "</td>");
    }
    document.write('<tr>');
    document.write('</table>');
}
```

Shown below is the output:
[image]

The output I want:

[image]

Comment: That would lead to invalid markup, a `br` directly within `tr` is not allowed.

Comment: Okay. Can you tell me an other way to do it?

Comment: @AraMalki what is your expected output ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a table? With multiple rows?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put 10 cells into a row (tr) and the next 10 into another row?

Comment: Uhh ... starting from `document.write` ... use e.g. [HTMLTable API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) instead.'

Comment: FWIW, typo near the end. The second `document.write('<tr>');` should be `document.write('</tr>');` (if using `document.write` for this).

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an if that checks the conditions you want. You shouldn't use `document.write`..

```
function printa() {
    document.write('<table>');
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i % 10 == 0 && i != numbers.length-1) {
            document.write('</tr>');
            document.write('<tr>');
        }
        document.write("<td>" + numbers[i] + "</td>");
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
    document.write('</table>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem. Much love.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function genTable(values, rowLength = 10) {
  let content = ''

  for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i += rowLength) {
    const tds = values.slice(i, i + rowLength).map(value => `<td>${value}</td>`)
    content += `<tr>${tds.join("")}</tr>`
  }

  return `<table>${content}</table>`
}

const numbers = new Array(30).fill().map((_,i) => i+1)
const table = genTable(numbers)

console.log(table)
document.write(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];

function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '100%';
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
  var trNum = Math.ceil(arr.length / 10);

  var arrNum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < trNum; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[arrNum]))
      tr.appendChild(td)
      arrNum++;
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr)
    console.log(trNum,i);
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl)
}
tableCreate();
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the data into simple 2d array to use the logic you are using as below,

```
function printa(numbers) {
    document.write('<table>');
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    numbers2 = numbers[i]
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers2.length; j++) {
        document.write("<td>" + numbers2[j] + "</td>");
    }

    document.write('</tr>');
    }
    document.write('</table>');
}

 printa([[1,2,3,4,5,6,22,3,45,23],[34,45,5677,12,34,23,11,22,67,23],[657,765,657,567,567,56,2,6,66,78]])
```